# Unable to identify where is the fault in a piece of code

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, reference, syntax-error

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String> ( );

String [] arpan = { "eggs" , "lazers" , "hats" ,"pie"  };

for ( String s: arpan )

        list1.add(s);

Collection<String> t = list1;//correct statement

t.add("umbrella");

Collections<String> t = list1;//wrong statement
```

In the above code the statement ***"Collection t = list1;"*** ***is correct*** but

***"Collections t = list1;"*** ***is wrong*** **why**?

**Note:-**I am aware of the fact that **Collections is a class which implements interface

Collection** and **ArrayList is a class which implements interface List which in turn 
extends interface Collection.** But ***i am not able to use this info to clear my confusion*** 
please help!!

Comment: _"I am aware of the fact that **Collections is a class which implements interface
Collection"_ I don't think so. Take a look at the javadoc. `public class Collections
extends Object`

Comment: Collections class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on or return collection. This is not Collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have defined two objects with the same name `t`, so the code can't even compile.

Secondly, Collections is a utility class and can not be defined as a generic type. That means you have to remove `<String>` from it's definition, but then your code still won't compile because `t` is a `List` object and can't be explicitly class to `Collections`.

If you cast it to `Collections`, then yes, your code will compile.

```
Collections t = (Collections)list1;
```

BUT it will generate an error when you run it because you have cast the wrong object type to `Collections` (a `List`). The exception would be

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Collections
```

The use of Collections is completely different from what you are trying to do here. Since it's an utility class, it's main use is to operate on other `Collection` objects and get various results from them.

A correct use would be something like, calculate minimum value from a `Collection` object

`Collections.min(list1)` would return `eggs` in your case, since it arranges them alphabetically and gets the first entry (the minimum).

Conclusion: The `Collections` class is not a `Collection`! It contains multiple static methods that operate on or return `Collection` objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections` is an utility class that contains methods that operate on subclasses of `Collection` class, such as `Collections.max(someCollection)`. You're trying to use it completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way Collection and Collections are both are different

Collection is interface which is implemented by all collection class like list ,set etc
while Collections is utility class which gives many method for performing various operation on
the collection like sorting searching etc

you can't assign collection object like list ,set to Collections class reference